# What is true about the three statements?

Tags: solution-verification

$C \ = \ \frac{5}{9}(F-32)$

The equation above shows how temperature F, measured in degrees Fahrenheit, relates to a temperature C, measured in degrees Celsius. Based on the equation, which of the following must be true?

I. A temperature increase of 1 degree Fahrenheit is equivalent to a temperature increase of $\frac{5}{9}$ degree Celsius

II. A temperature increase of 1 degree Celsius is equivalent to a temperature increase of 1.8 degrees Fahrenheit.

III. A temperature increase of $\frac{5}{9}$ degree Fahrenheit is equivalent to a temperature increase of 1 degree Celsius.

A) I only
B) II only
C) III only
D) I and II only

I can only say that $I \ = \ C \ = \ \frac{5*1}{9} \ = \ \frac{5}{9}$ so I is true. But is II and III true? If it is, what is the answer?

Is A) the answer?

Comment: Hint: for II and III, rewrite the equation as f = 9/5 c + 32. Only one of II or III can be true

Comment: @Srini is D the answer?

Comment: Yes, both 1 and 2 are right

Comment: @Srini can you write it in the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Given C= 5/9(F−32)
Making F the subject of the formula
F= 9/5 C+32
If F' = F + 1
C′= 5/9(F′−32)
Substituting with the value of F'
C′= 5/9(F+1−32)
C'= 5/9(F−32)+ 9/5×1
C′= C+5/9
A temperature increase of 1 degree Fahrenheit is equivalent to a temperature increase of 5/9 degree Celsius.
Statement I is true.

If C' = C+1
F′= 9/5 ​C′+32
F′= 9/5(C+1)+32
F′=(9/5 C+32)+ 9/5
​F′=F+9/5
F′=F+1.8
A temperature increase of 1 degree Celsius is equivalent to a temperature increase of 1.8 degrees Fahrenheit.
Statement II is true.

If F′=F+ 5/9
​C′= 5/9(F′−32)
C′= 5/9(F+ 5/9−32)
C′= 5/9(F−32)+ 5/9 × 5/9
​C′=C+ 25/81
​Hence, a temperature increase of
9/5 degree Fahrenheit is equivalent to a temperature increase of
25/81 degree Celsius.
Statement III is false.

Therefore D is the answer.
Here is a resource to read further about [degrees Fahrenheit](https://lookbooklogic.com/convert-fahrenheit-to-celsius) and [degree Celsius](https://lookbooklogic.com/convert-celsius-to-fahrenheit)

Comment: About 3 years late and I've already moved on from being bad at maths and moved on to Puzzling; but hey an answer is an answer!

Comment: Well I am so bad at puzzling but all the best